# Finding the number of orbitals on a central atom

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, orbitals, atoms, vsepr-theory

In $\ce{BeCl2}$ the number of orbitals on central atom, i.e. on beryllium, are 2. In $\ce{BF3}$, the number of orbitals on central atom , i.e. on boron, are 3.

Similarly in $\ce{NH3}$ there are 4, on $\ce{PCl5}$, $\ce{SF4}$, and $\ce{ClF3}$ there are 5. But how?

Comment: Consider $BeCl_2$ with E.C $[He]2s^2$. E.C in excited state will be $[He]2s^12p^1$. These two orbitals ($2s$ and $2p$) get hybridised to form $sp$ hybridized orbitals. Thus, in your language number of orbitals on central atom is $2$. Similarly you can try for other compounds.

Answer (score 3):

**According to the question, it is totally not clear that whether you want to know filled orbitals or total orbital (filled + vacant).** Well, but after seeing the examples you gave, it can be concluded that you are talking only about filled orbitals. **As I'm not clear and assuming that you are only talking about filled orbitals, so if you are talking about total, leave a comment.**

As each [orbital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) contains 2 electrons, therefore it is easy to find number of filled orbitals.

The number of filled orbitals in central atom will be equal to **the sum of number of bonds and number of lone pairs present on central atom.**

**Example**

As in case of $\ce{BeCl2}$, $\ce{Be}$ makes 2 bonds (both with $\ce{Cl}$) and have no lone pair, therefore,

$\text{No. of filled orbitals} = 2$

**Let us take another example of $\ce{NH3}$.**

In case of $\ce{NH3}$, $\ce{N}$ makes 3 bonds (each with $\ce{H}$) and have 1 lone pair, therefore,

$\text{No. of filled orbitals} = 4$

**Take another example of $\ce{ClF3}$**

In this case, the central atom $\ce{Cl}$ makes 3 bonds with $\ce{F}$ by **sharing its one electron in each bond** and have 2 lone pairs on it. (As $\ce{Cl}$ have 7 electrons, 3 shared in bonding and 4 left = 2 lone pairs.) Therefore,

$\text{No. of filled orbitals} = 5$

Hope, now everything is clear to you!